# How to prevent empty space lines while iterating a .txt file using FOR loop in batch Script

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, space

I have one .txt file with text and some empty space lines. While doing some operations in .txt file by using for loop, found originally contained empty space lines are gone.

Example :
I have a temp.txt file with below input :

```
#
 Require
 #

 #Rel task
 #
 
 HOST_ID=

 ACTIVATE_ID

 #
 #
```

After doing some operations using FOR Loop I am getting result in same .txt file like below :

```
#
 Require
 #
 #Rel task
 #
 HOST_ID=56767\Ether
 ACTIVATE_ID
 #
 #
```

So, I don't want to ignore those empty space lines.
I tried to use `usebacq` keyword in for loop, but not working.
I tried each and possible way to do this, but failed everytime.

Here, is my code :

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set rem=56767\Ether
set "textFile=temp.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    
    if !line!==HOSTID= (
        set "foo=!line:HOSTID=HOSTID=%rem%!"
        set "line=!foo:~0,-1!"
    )
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
:EXIT
pause
```

In above code, I am doing to append some extra string in front of provided string in same .txt file.

Comment: `@echo off` this is not bash. I tried to remove unrelevant tags

Comment: @Jetchisel what is Powah shell? Do you mean `powershell`? far from it, this is `batch-file` code.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%i in ('type "%textFile%"  ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> %textFile%') do (` then use `%%j` instead of `%%i`

Comment: @Gerhard. Its working for me. Thanks a lot for your help. Can you please tell me why you have used `[]`  in delims.

Comment: `for /F` ignores empty lines by design, so `find /N` can used to prepend `[` plus line number plus `]`, which makes the lines no longer appear empty to `for /F`; the prefixes are then removed via the `tokens` and `delims` options…

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your file has a space before `HOST_ID=` like it currently does, but both with/without space has been added in this example:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "rem=56767\Ether"
set "textFile=temp.txt"
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break^>"%textFile%"') do (
    set "line=%%j"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if "!line!" == "HOST_ID=" set "line=!line!%rem%"
    if "!line!" == " HOST_ID=" set "line=!line!%rem%" 
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
:EXIT
pause
```

Delimiters are `[]` because we add line numbers which you do not see as `[n]` before each entry by using `find /V /N ""`. This way we retain the empty lines.

Comment: See the eomment in the bottom of the answer about `delims=[]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method, the idea being that you don't need delayed expansion, and, *(for safety)*, you're not trying to read from and write to the same file.

What it does is to first determine if your required string exists in the file, if it doesn't the script closes, if it does it sets a variable to its line number. Then the file is parsed outputting the contents of each line untouched except for the line matching the saved variable, where it appends `%rem%` to it.

When the script ends your original file should exist along side it with a `.bak` extension.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "rem=56767\Ether"
Set "textFile=temp.txt"

Set "lineNum="
For /F Delims^=: %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /INR "\<HOST_ID=\>" "%textFile%" 2^>NUL^"')Do Set "lineNum=%%G"
If Not Defined lineNum GoTo :EOF
For %%G In ("%textFile%")Do Set "_=%%~nG.bak" & Copy /Y "%%G" "%%~nG.bak">NUL
(For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /N "^" "%_%"^"')Do If %%G NEq %lineNum% (Echo=%%H)Else Echo %%H%rem%)>"%textFile%"
Pause
```